# Check if byte string represents float or int

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, floating-point, integer

I have some `byte strings` and I don't know if they are integers or floats.

Lets create some example data:

```py
import numpy as np
arr_int =   np.array([17,    int(1e10),  34567])
arr_float = np.array([17.17, 1e10/np.pi, 34567.8])
arr_int_b = arr_int.tobytes()
# b'\x11\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xe4\x0bT\x02\x00\x00\x00\x07\x87\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
arr_float_b = arr_float.tobytes()
# b'\xecQ\xb8\x1e\x85+1@"\xd0\xba}G\xb7\xe7A\xd9\xce\xf7S\xe3\xa5\x0b@'
```

If I read them with `numpy.frombuffer(.., dtype=float/int)` and use the **wrong** `dtype` I get either really large values (float->int) or really small values (int->float).

```
arr_float2int = np.frombuffer(arr_float_b, dtype=int)
# array([4625526143032250860, 4748965849765433378, 4674983775839033754])
arr_int2float = np.frombuffer(arr_int_b, dtype=float)
# array([8.39911598e-323, 4.94065646e-314, 1.70783672e-319])
```

Right now I use a check like this to make sure I get the right results:

```
arr = np.frombuffer(arr_b, dtype=int)
if np.mean(arr) > 1e12:
    arr = np.frombuffer(arr_b, dtype=float)
```

This works in my case, because I know that I won't have integers with values larger than 10000.
And I also know that I wont have floats with really small values.
But I am curious if there is a more general (and safe) way to check this.

But I guess if all integers and all floats are allowed it is not possible to tell the difference from the byte string:

```
np.frombuffer(np.array([1e-320]).tobytes(), dtype=int)
# array([2024])
np.frombuffer(np.array([int(46e17)]).tobytes(), dtype=float)
# array([0.35129566])
```

Comment: You can not see, based on the bytes, if it is a float or not. It is just an *interpretation* of binary data. You better encode it somewhere in the bytestream what the type is.

Comment: Example: All bits zero is both integer 0 and float 0.0

Comment: Consider 123456789012345678.0.  As a `float` it loses precision.  As an integer it is approaching the edge of encodable integers - but can be encoded exactly, even though it looks like an float with the `".0"`.  As I see it, a string can potential encode as both with various limitations of precision and range.

Comment: Maybe ask A) "Check if byte string represents float" with the outcome of 1) any non converted charterers 2) precision loss, 3) within range? and then **separately** B) "Check if byte string represents int" 1) any non converted charterers 2) precision loss, 3) within range?